# Buggy behavior in matplotlib pcolormesh with FFT arrays?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, fft

I am trying to reproduce the example of the Gabor transform that it is in his wikipedia entry, and I do not know if it is a bug or I am missing something. The example is the calculate the Gabor transform of a sinusoidal signal:

[image: The function]

To plot the frequencies sorted, I create an unsorted axis. Then I use mesh grid to create 2D axes and plot with pcolormesh. Here is the piece of the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridsp

dt = 0.05
x = np.arange(-50.0,50.0,dt)
y = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * x)
Nx = len(x)
w = np.fft.fftfreq(Nx,dt)

sigma = 1.0 / 3.0 
neg = np.where (x <= 0.0)
pos = np.where (x > 0.0)

T,W = np.meshgrid(x,w)
func = np.zeros(Nx)
tmp = np.zeros(Nx,dtype='complex64')
gabor = np.zeros((Nx,Nx))

func[neg] = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * x[neg])
func[pos] = np.sin(4.0 * np.pi * x[pos])

for it in range(Nx):    
        tmp[:] = np.fft.fft(func[:] * np.exp( - ( x[it] - x[:] ) * ( x[it] - x[:] ) / 2.0 / sigma / sigma ) ) 

        gabor[:,it] = np.real(np.conj(tmp) * tmp)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,10),facecolor='white')
gs = gridsp.GridSpec(2, 1)

ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0,0])
ax1.plot(x,func,'r',linewidth=2)
ax1.axis('tight')
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x),max(x),1.) )
ax1.set_xlabel('time',fontsize=20)
ax1.set_ylabel(r'$\sin{time}$',fontsize=20)
ax1.set_xlim([-6.0,6.0])


ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1,0])
surf1 = ax2.pcolormesh(T,W,gabor,shading='gouraud')
ax2.axis('tight')
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(min(x),max(x),2.) )
ax2.set_yticks(np.arange(min(w),max(w),2.) )
ax2.set_xlabel('time',fontsize=20)
ax2.set_ylabel('frequency',fontsize=20)
ax2.set_xlim([-6.0,6.0])
ax2.set_ylim([-4.0,4.0])

gs.tight_layout(fig)
plt.show()
```

Here is the figure I get,

[image: Only negative frequencies. The lower part of the array is plotted]

It seems that the upper part of the plot is reduced to zero. If I try it using fftshift when I create the transform and the axis,

```
for it in range(Nx):
        tmp[:] = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(func[:] * np.exp( - ( x[it] - x[:] ) * ( x[it] - x[:] ) / 2.0 / sigma / sigma ) ) )     


        gabor[:,it] = np.real(np.conj(tmp) * tmp)

T,W = np.meshgrid(x,np.fft.fftshift(w))
```

Then I get this figure:

[image: Finally, the right figure]!

It seems that pcolormesh routine can not flip upside down the array as it is usually done in 1D plots. does anybody know exactly why it is doing this?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem lies in `W`. Or actually in `w`. When `w` is plotted:

[image]

Thus `pcolormesh` receives non-monotonic Y coordinates and gets confused. If you look at the description of `pcolor` or `pcolormesh` it is clear they cannot do anything reasonable with non-monotonic data.

So, your `gabor` is fine:

```
ax.imshow(gabor)
```

as you can see:

[image]

There are several possibilities how to fix this. One of them is to feed both `W` and `gabor` to `fftshift` that way the frequencies will roll back to monotonic. Or - if you want to have the figure as above (negative frequencies on the top), just add the maximum frequency to all negative values of `W`.

It might also be cleaner to supply `pcolormesh` with `x` and `w` instead of `T` and `W`.

---

If you want performance, you might be better of with `imshow` (it can be used when the data is equispaced in both dimensions. The only slight problem is the calculation of extents (which actually may be slightly off even in the question). The extents tell the outer limets of the highest, lowest, leftmost and rightmost pixels. However, the pixel vectors only tell the centers of the pixels.

We need to know the following:

- number of points in X direction (`num_x`)
- number of points in Y direction (`num_y`)
- value of the first and last x sample (`x0`, `x1`)
- value of the first and last y sample (`y0`, `y1`)

After that we can use `imshow` to show the data with correct scaling:

```
dx = 1. * (x1 - x0) / (num_x-1)
dy = 1. * (y1 - y0) / (num_y-1)

ax.imshow(img, extent=[x0 - dx/2, x1 + dx/2, y0 - dy/2, y1 + dy/2], origin='lower', interpolation='nearest')
```

So, applied to the question's data:

```
gabor_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(gabor, axes=0)
w_shifted = np.fft.fftshift(w)

x0 = x[0]
x1 = x[-1]
w0 = w_shifted[0]
w1 = w_shifted[-1]

dx = 1.*(x1-x0) / (len(x) - 1)
dw = 1.*(w1-w0) / (len(w) - 1)

ax2.imshow(gabor_shifted, extent=[x0-dx/2, x1+dx/2, w0-dw/2, w1+dw/2], interpolation='nearest', origin='lower', aspect='auto')
ax2.grid('on', color='w')
ax2.ylim(-4,4)
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I haven't realised that pcolormesh doesn't work with non-monotonic arrays (however you can expect this from my question).